# How to generate a list using monoid concat?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, monoids, fp-ts

I have been doing functional programming for quite some time now, but I am new to monoids and other pure abstractions. I am wondering if there is a way to generate a list of values by using `concat` function defined for a monoid?

For example, with 0 as identity (unit) and `+` as `concat`, integers become a monoid. If I want to have a sequence of ordered integers, I could just apply `+` to the first integer I need and `1` (which would be a step here), then repeat the process for the result and so on. This would generate a list like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]`.

Similarly for more complex monoids, if there is Event monoid defined, with special value as identity and `concat` such that it takes two Events and produces a new one keeping the same interval, I could have a sequence of `[ Event(Today, 12:00), Event(Today, 12:10), Event(Today, 12:20) ]` (so the interval is 10 minutes).

**My question is:** is there any standard pattern/abstraction/way of genereting such sequences by applying `concat` to previous item and a step/interval? I am using `fp-ts` library and I tried to find something that could do it, but without any luck. I could use `unfold` to generate an array of values, but this function passes only one value to the callback while I need two values for `concat` to work

Comment: Why do you think `unfold` only works with integers?

Comment: I believe you should just define your `concat` method. https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Monoid.ts.html

Comment: @Bergi sorry I got confused myself, I have edited the part about `unfold`.

Comment: "*I need two values for concat to work*" - the second value is the `step` (i.e. `1` in your first example, `10min` in your second)

Comment: This makes sense. But I thought that both parameters to `concat` should be of the same type. My Event is a _tagged union_ wrapping Date (to allow me to define `empty` as EmptyEvent, as there is no native empty for a date), interval is a `number`. Or am I overcomplicating here?

Answer (score 0):

> this function passes only one value to the callback while I need two values for `concat` to work

Here's the type of `unfold` from the `Array` module:

```
export declare const unfold: <A, B>(b: B, f: (b: B) => O.Option<readonly [A, B]>) => A[]
```

Although it may seem like `B` can only be ‘one value’, you can always return a tuple so that you have access to more than one value in `f`.

[fp-ts does not currently support infinite lists](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/issues/1180), so here’s an example of using a `length` parameter to limit the size of the result:

```
import * as A from 'fp-ts/Array'
import {none, some} from 'fp-ts/Option'
import type {Monoid} from 'fp-ts/Monoid'

const concatList = <M>(M: Monoid<M>) => (step: M) => (length: number): M[] =>
  A.unfold<M, [M, number]>([M.empty, 0], ([prev, currentLength]) => {
    if (currentLength === length) return none
    const next = M.concat(prev, step)
    return some([next, [next, currentLength + 1]])
  })
```

Usage:

```
import {MonoidSum} from 'fp-ts/number'

concatList(MonoidSum)(1)(5) // [1, 2, 3,  4,  5]
concatList(MonoidSum)(3)(5) // [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```